# Character Varieties- reference request

Tags: reference-request, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I will start learning about character varieties.  I need to learn about Teichmuller spaces and how to consider them as  components of "some character variety".

Can someone recommend some textbooks or papers, please? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

William Goldman has proven that the components of the character variety of the fundamental group of a surface $S$ into $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the induced Euler classes of the representations (which by the Milnor-Wood inequality are $\leq |\chi(S)|$), with the maximal and minimal Euler classes corresponding to copies of Teichmuller space. Have a look at [his paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01410200) and references therein.